# Image auto height to scaled width

Tags: html, css

I have certain images that are smaller in width which i stretch the width to fit the container, however  would like the hieght to scale up as well, thanks in advance, Phil

Comment: In lieu of css approach, you could calculate the aspect ratio of the original, then calculate projected height dynamically from the width..

Comment: Please include more code next time.

Comment: I did this with a youtube video, scales height with the browser as well as width.  You could adapt it for anything but may be a little overkill:  https://gist.github.com/dcondrey/647fcdda17cd23715872

Comment: He's overcomplicating it. If CSS can't handle it, then he has a conflict somewhere in his code. But instead of debugging it the right way, he's going to counter-conflict his conflict. This is how junky code is born.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to specify the height.

Take a look to my example, here is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/d575tr49/

**Here is the HTML**

```
<div class="ele">
    <img src="http://viralstash.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/521013543_1385596410.jpg" border="0" />
</div>
```

**Here is the CSS**

```
.ele {
    outline: red solid 1px;
    width: 250px;
}
.ele img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

If you control the width on the Parent element, just the with, you will not need to worry about the width and height values of the image.

The image it self will set its width using the parents size, and by default the height value will be proportional to the width, so no need to specify the height value at all, not even in the parent.

Comment: sorry, image height still not auto sizing only the width

Comment: did you check my jsfiddle, its working in there, play with it and you will see. Maybe is something with your source. Maybe you should post the css and html you have so far on a jsfiddle.

Comment: yes, thanks for the example, however the image itself is larger than any height and width in the code, what i want to do is enlarge the image to fit the width and also enlarge the height automatically to the same proportion of width, thanks.

Comment: Which is the targeted width you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

In your css:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

CSS can naturally handle this. The image will automatically take up 100% of the width of its container, and the height will scale to match.

Comment: Tried this method, the width will fit perfectly however the height will not scale up to match :/ thanks.

Comment: Please create a fiddle or codepen with the example code so I can debug. You have conflicting CSS somewhere because this is a pretty basic CSS thing.

Comment: Make sure you add the !important declaration (height: auto !important;) to ensure cross-browser compatibility (especially older broswers, i.e 6, 7, etc).

Comment: Updated answer to reflect. Should work now to override other styles.